# Header files included in stdafx.h are not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, stdafx.h

i'm using visual studio 2008. I include some includes ( boost headers ) in the stdafx.h but, now they arent found by the compiler ( lexical_cast not found for example ). I included stdafx.h on the top of the cpp file. So what i'm doing wrong?

Thank's in advance

edit:: i've set the include path correctly, if i'm including the boost header in the cpp -file directly, everything works.

Comment: Have you told Visual Studio where to find those headers?

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

Menu -> Tools -> Options -> unwind Project and Solutions -> VC++ Directories -> "Show directories for:" -> choose Include files -> Add the path to your Boost directory